# Transition azure app service in mode classic to management?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an azure web app in mode classic. Now, i wish transition it to mode management. Is it possible ? If yes, how can i do it?

Comment: You should just do it and see what the problems are. We can not tell you what will fail without knowing the code.

Comment: Thank peter for your answer. Indeed, il sought the powershell script in the internet for doing it. But i did not succeed to find it :( So i don't know if is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a Web App from classic to Azure Resource Management. You need to create a new ARM-based app service, then re-create / redeploy your web app to your new app service.

Comment: Hi David, i got this answer from the microsoft forum : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e6c2df4a-365f-4967-9118-5c7e6f19bd0c/transition-azure-app-service-in-mode-classic-to-management-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: What do you think about it ? Thank